# Perl piping some out of script and some to the screen

Tags: perl

How do I pipe some output to screen and some other selected output, out of the Perl script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using different file handles.

By default you'll have both `STDOUT` and `STDERR`. The `print` function in Perl is really short hand for `print STDOUT`.

In your terminal `STDOUT` is given the file handle `1` and `STDERR` is given the file handle `2`.

Here's an example of printing to each file handle and redirecting each to /dev/null.

```
$ perl -e 'print STDOUT "foo\n"; print STDERR "bar\n";'
foo
bar
$ perl -e 'print STDOUT "foo\n"; print STDERR "bar\n";' 1> /dev/null
bar
% perl -e 'print STDOUT "foo\n"; print STDERR "bar\n";' 2> /dev/null
foo
```

- The first command prints both.
- The second command throws away `STDOUT` and prints only `STDERR`
- The third command throws away `STDERR` and prints only `STDOUT`

You can also declare your own file handles (e.g., a log file) and print to that instead. See `perldoc -f open`.

Comment: I cant run perldoc, the system crashes. Could you note how to declare my own non-file handle?

Comment: Just print to `STDOUT`. It will go to the screen.

Comment: i know that, there is STDOUT and STDERR, but i need to make my own, third handle which i can pipe specifically out of the program.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify your question with some example code and where you want the output to go.

Comment: I want some output to go to the screen, and some to be piped by 'number> some_bash_script'. Sorry but the sample code is exactly what I'm missing.

Comment: What you want to go to the screen use `STDERR`. What you want to go to the file use `STDOUT`. See the second example above. This does exactly what you asked.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I just assumed STDERR had something to do with error reporting, as its name implies. So I'll use STDERR to pass stuff around that has nothing to do with errors.

Comment: if your system crashes when you run perldoc, then your first priority is to fix your system.

Comment: also, misusing STDERR is generally a bad idea.  use named pipes instead.  or if you know in advance what external program you want to pipe the data to, you can open a pipe to that program from within your perl script.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to read the perlipc documentation, in particular the section on Named Pipes.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Named-Pipes

perlipc - Perl interprocess communication (signals, fifos, pipes, safe subprocesses, sockets, and semaphores)

If you need two-way (read & write) communication with an external program, then the IPC::Open2 or IPC::Open3 modules (standard perl lib, also documented in the URL above) will be useful.